# Mocking laravel models static call

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

## Background

I have a system with a microservices setup. A few of these microservices run a laravel installation. In order to share some key models, a repo was shared using git/packagist.

Here is a diagram:

- `Microservice A`
- `Microservice B`
- ...

These both share `Library C`. This library has the shared models. This is outside of a normal laravel installation, but the composer includes `"laravel/framework": "^9.0"`.

*Note: There good external reasons to share the functionality - the microservices have come out of a monolith and are still developing fluidly and are not mature enough for a complete decoupling. This will come in time.*

I wish to unit test these models.

### Specifics

The requirement is that several models (`User`, `Customer` .. etc) all require addresses. Normalising these out would introduce complexity elsewhere that is not appropriate yet, so a trait is good for now. These have UK postcodes that require a specific validation against a database. Postcodes are modelled using a `Postcode` model.

I created a trait : `AddressTrait`. This offers some useful functionality. Included in this is a Postcode validation. This intercepts a set request in laravel (eg: `$user->postcode = 'AB10 1AB`)

```php
    /**
     * Automatically updates the log/lat from the postcode
     * @param $value
     */
    public function setPostcodeAttribute($value): void
    {
        // update postcode
        $this->attributes['postcode'] = strtoupper($value);

        // now update lat/long
        $postcode = Postcode::where('pcd', '=', str_replace(' ', '', $value))
            ->orWhere('pcd', '=', $value)
            ->first();

        if ($postcode) {
            $this->attributes['latitude'] = $postcode->latitude;
            $this->attributes['longitude'] = $postcode->longitude;
        }
    }
```

This works as expected.
Note - it is to be extended quite a bit further with much more complexity, but this is step 1 and completely represents the problem.

### Testing

If I interact with the postcode attribute, such as `$user->postcode = 'AB10 1AB`, this attempts to load the `Postcode` from the database, and the following error occurs:

- `Error : Call to a member function connection() on null`

^ This is expected.

I would like to unit test this: ie. no reaching out the class and mocking system/functional elements. Thus, I need to mock the `Postcode` load (`Postcode::where(..) ..` ).

As this is a static call, I have used mockery (`"mockery/mockery": "dev-master"`).

Here is the current attempt:

```php
// ...

use Mockery;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

// ...

    public function testPostcodeProcessing(): void
    {
        $postcode_value = 'AB10 1AB';
        $postcode_content = [
            'pcd' => $postcode_value,
            'latitude' => '0.1',
            'longitude' => '0.2'
        ];

        $mock_postcode = Mockery::mock(Postcode::class);
        $mock_postcode->shouldReceive('where')->once()->andReturn($mock_postcode);
        $mock_postcode->shouldReceive('orWhere')->once()->andReturn($mock_postcode);
        $mock_postcode->shouldReceive('first')->once()->andReturn($postcode_content);

        $model = $this->createTraitImplementedClass();
        $model->postcode = $postcode_value;
    }


    protected function createTraitImplementedClass(): Model
    {
        return new class extends Model {
            use AddressTrait;
        };
    }
```

### TLDR question

I would like to unit test this function: ie. no reaching out the class and mocking.

- How do I mock a laravel/eloquent static call, given that:

  - this is to be tested outside laravel
  - there is no database connection

OR

- How do I refactor this to allow it to be more testable

### Super TLDR;

How do I mock the load in:

```php
    public function tldr(): void
    {
        //  this eloquent lookup needs to be mocked (not moved, refactored etc etc..)
        $postcode = Postcode::where('pcd', '=', 'AB10 1AB')->first();
    }
```

Notes:

- These are unit tests
- I would prefer to do this "the laravel way", but given the unusual circumstances things such as `mockery` might make sense
- May be a gotcha: I am using the phpunit `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` - not the usual PHP test case. This is not a "requirement", but I imagined a mock shouldn't need the extended features.

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: I am a little bit confused honestly. So, first of all, the "laravel way" is NEVER mocking any eloquent, builder, or core functionality except it is a `bind`, a `singleton`, or a `facade`, else you never mock core functionality, you must use that functionality. So my question is, why do you need to test if the `connection` error happens? I need to understand a little bit more why you need to test that and which exact line of code should be throwing that

Comment: I want to mock the postcode lookup. I am not interested in mocking core functionality at all.
I do not need to test the connection error.  For the sake of illustration above, I pointed out that this error occurs if I do NOT mock it. 
When I attempted to mock `Postcode::where(...)` it still gives the same error, proving that it fails to mock.

Comment: I am still confused, the only thing you should test in there is if it returns a desired postcode, if you have another postcode (that one is not returned) and if it returns `null` (due to the `if` after that line), you do not need to test if it throws an exception or whatever, you can't test 1000 cases (you have to test a lot of CORE framework cases and that makes no sense). The only way for you to test this, is to create a lot of postcodes that will NOT match the desired query, and only 1 that will.

Comment: "I am still confused, the only thing you should test in there is if it returns a desired postcode" <-- sort of, but not really.

I need to prove that the entire function `setPostcodeAttribute($value)` works. 
If you run the test, the static call `Postcode::where(...)...` tries to connect to the database. I want to mock this call to prevent it doing so, and return predetermined results for testing the rest of `setPostcodeAttribute($value)` .

Comment: @elb98rm but why? why is the User class tested for Postcode class lookup function ?

Comment: Because the `AddressTrait`/ `User` function `setPostcodeAttribute($value)` is not tested and cannot be tested without mocking the static call `Postcode::where(...)...`.
If you look at the code I am actually talking about the `AddressTrait::setPostcodeAttribute($value)` function. I am testing the AddressTrait.

Comment: @elb98rm you are having this "issue" because you usually don't test like that, again the "laravel way" is using a feature test, where you fully test this outcome, it wouldo involve calling a controller, executing a job, a command, or something else, but when you need to unit test a model, usually you never unit test a model, because remember, there are a lot of thing behind the scenes going on, it is not just a plain class, you have a lot of stuff in there, so you are having issue because you are wrongly approaching this, that is why it looks "complex", but do NOT mock ANY model

Comment: This is not an answer to "how do I mock a statically called class in laravel".

Comment: @elb98rm sorry you are not getting the answer you want, sometimes asking for "can I sum 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 to get = 2?" the answer is going to be "looks like you have something wrong to end up suming 1/2 4 times to get 2, it is easier to do 1 + 1", so what you are trying to do is a code smell, you have something wrong in that logic that you ended up with. You don't belive me? Check my profile and see some links I have in here, you will see how I help with `testing`, you have something wrong so you ended up with bad code, don't take it personal please

Comment: If I were going to write a codebase, the "correct way" would not be static calls. I agree this is a code smell. The laravel authors seem to find it fine. It's their preferred method.  I am searching for a way to deal with their code smell. However, i'm focussed on the answer, not the code smell, which is out of my control. Sticking to the question is not personal, it's logical.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After some extensive looking into this, I've found the answer using mockery aliases. This is done as follows:

### Isolate this class/test from the remainder of the tests

If you create an alias, this overwrites the class globally for the rest of the current process. It's risky, but this can be done and many of the problems sidestepped by running the test/class in a separate process.

This can be done using the docblock:

```php
/**
 * At a class level
 * @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */
```

### Mock the class as an `alias`

Aliases mock static classes. This is the key point I was missing during my question - I missed the `alias:` part.

```php
    public function testPostcodeProcessing(): void
    {
        // define this first to intercept the global instantiation
        $mock_postcode = Mockery::mock('alias:' . Postcode::class);

        // ... 
    }
```

The above mock will override ALL Postcode classes in this test/test class. Thus, it should be declared first.

### Add your responses and assertions

This is entirely up to you, but here is the example and assertions I created.

```php
    /*
     * Tests that the postcode processes correctly.
     */
    public function testPostcodeProcessing(): void
    {
        // define this first to intercept the global instantiation
        $mock_postcode = Mockery::mock('alias:' . Postcode::class);

        // set up a returned class
        $returned_postcode = new Postcode();
        $postcode_pcd = 'AB10 1AB';
        $postcode_latitude = 0.1;
        $postcode_longitude = 0.2;
        $returned_postcode->pcd = $postcode_pcd;
        $returned_postcode->latitude = $postcode_latitude;
        $returned_postcode->longitude = $postcode_longitude;

        // Set up the mock
        $mock_postcode->shouldReceive('where')->once()->andReturn($mock_postcode);
        $mock_postcode->shouldReceive('orWhere')->once()->andReturn($mock_postcode);
        $mock_postcode->shouldReceive('first')->once()->andReturn($returned_postcode);

        $model = $this->createTraitImplementedClass();
        $model->postcode = $postcode_pcd;

        $this->assertEquals($postcode_pcd, $model->postcode, 'The postcode object pcd was not set');
        $this->assertEquals($postcode_latitude, $model->latitude, 'The postcode object latitude was not loaded');
        $this->assertEquals($postcode_longitude, $model->longitude, 'The postcode object longitude was not loaded');
    }
```

Note - these are "step 1" tests. The real class is more complex, and the test will be more complex. However, this gives the core solution to the instantiation issue.

### TLDR;

- Run this in a separate process
- Use an Alias (and remember to declare it as an alias - `alias:SomeClass`)

Comment: If someone applies a global scope, you will also have to mock that, or any feature new stuff, that is why you never mock models, eloquent, or similar stuff, you must do a database "request". This test looks more like a CORE framework test than an app test, but if it works, there you go, you will learn the hard way you should not do it this way

Comment: What do you think "core" tests are? I am testing ZERO framework elements. Please back your assertation up with a line of code that directly tests code that is outside the function I am writing.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8d2cbbe6584a919bc95af6b37d18714d1f816fda/tests/Database/DatabaseEloquentModelTest.php#L594-L610) is just an example, see how they are moking basic stuff like `where`, those are core framework tests... Again, do whatever you want, this is just a warning for anyone else landing on this question/answer in the future.

Comment: You didn't respond to my direct request.

Comment: Please mind the tone, @matiaslauriti brings valid points which i agree with, your mock care about multiple frameworks elements, you could get around of by using a test database setup and not mocking a model. This is inconvenient and inefficient use of anyone's time. If you are lucky to write code where testing is allowed and encouraged, it is not well spent time to mock models and assert methods we already know works. And if it was not a hint you got, getting in a fairly harsh debate about pretty fair solution suggestions is not a good trait in my honest opinion.

Answer (score 1):

What if you abstracted away the part where you get the postcode?

```php
public function setPostcodeAttribute($value): void
{
    // update postcode
    $this->attributes['postcode'] = strtoupper($value);

    // now update lat/long
    $postcode = $this->getPostCode($value);

    if ($postcode) {
        $this->attributes['latitude'] = $postcode->latitude;
        $this->attributes['longitude'] = $postcode->longitude;
    }
}

// you could make this method protected as well
// but if you do, your need to call the shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods()
// when creating your mock
public function getPostCode(string $value): ?Postcode
{
    return Postcode::where('pcd', '=', str_replace(' ', '', $value))
        ->orWhere('pcd', '=', $value)
        ->first();
}
```

If you do it like this, you no longer need to mock Eloquent Query builder at all. Partially mocking a class that uses that Address trait should give you what you need. I'm not sure if this works for anonymous classes though

```php
public function test_existing_postcode()
{
    // Arrange
    $userMock = Mockery::mock(User::class)->makePartial();
    $user = new User;
    $postcode_value = 'AB10 1AB';
    $postcode = new PostCode([
        'pcd' => $postcode_value,
        'latitude' => '0.1',
        'longitude' => '0.2'
    ]);

    // Expect
    $userMock->expects()
        ->getPostCode($postcode_value)
        ->andReturn($postcode);

    // Act
    $user->postcode = $postcode_value;

    // Assert
    $this->assertEquals($user->latitude, $postcode->latitude);
    $this->assertEquals($user->longitude, $postcode->longitude);
}

public function test_nonexisting_postcode()
{
    // Arrange
    $userMock = Mockery::mock(User::class)->makePartial();
    $user = new User;
    $postcode_value = 'AB10 1AB';

    // Expect
    $userMock->expects()
        ->getPostCode($postcode_value)
        ->andReturn(null);

    // Act
    $user->postcode = $postcode_value;

    // Assert
    $this->assertNull($user->latitude);
    $this->assertNull($user->longitude);
}
```

---

Although I wouldn't recommend it, if you had a static method inside the Postcode model.

```php
class Postcode extends Model
{
    public static function getPostcodeByValue(string $value): ?Postcode
    {
        return Postcode::...
    }
}
```

You could mock it with

```php
$postcodeMock = \Mockery::mock('alias:Postcode');
$postcodeMock->shouldReceive('getPostcodeByValue')
    ->with($value)
    ->andReturn($postcode);
```

I'm not sure if `expects()` works, but if it does, you can also write this as

```php
$postcodeMock = \Mockery::mock('alias:Postcode');
$postcodeMock->expects()
    ->getPostcodeByValue($value)
    ->andReturn($postcode);
```

Important: for this to work, the `Postcode` class should not have been loaded (by this or any previous tests). It's that fragile.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but it is just sidestepping the problem. I want to mock a static call, and this is the simplest example in the code. There will be others that may not lend themselves to this.  "How do I then test the abstraction?"

Side note, you can always add anonymous functions that simply pass through to protected functions (this is a top unit testing hack: extend the class and wrap protected functions).

Comment: [Mocking static calls](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/public_static_properties.html) (or rather [Aliasing](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#creating-test-doubles-aliasing)) is not really recommended by Mockery.  As a rule of thumb, you should not try to mock what you don't own (the query builder functionality of an eloquent model).

Comment: I own both models. This is not a third party, it is simply a different class. If I were mocking an third party API.. sure, this is a valid criticism. But I own both.
Either way, the question of how to mock a static call remains.

Comment: I've edited the answer to provide a way to mock static methods

Comment: Thanks, but I realised this just moves the "I don't know how to mock static calls in laravel" to another class, which my testing will bump into later.

Comment: It depends on which static calls you're trying to mock. Simple methods should work. Things that rely on vendor code (like the query builder) should not be mocked directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your method more test friendly

- Injectable external class to remove hidden dependencies
- Keep the formatting/input validation outside if it is not related to "something" structural
- Separate functionalities or the S in SOLID principles (move the lookup for Postcode instance to where it belongs)

like this

```
 /**
     * Automatically updates the log/lat from the postcode
     * @param string $value
     * @param Postcode $postcode
     */
    public function setPostcodeAttribute($value, Postcode $postcode = null): void
    {
        // update postcode
        $this->attributes['postcode'] = $value;

        if ($postcode) {
            $this->attributes['latitude'] = $postcode->latitude;
            $this->attributes['longitude'] = $postcode->longitude;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, this misunderstands the class. 

`$value` is a string that should be looked up to find a `Postcode` object. At the point of setting, `Postcode` is not known.
It needs to be looked up.. you can't dependency inject something you don't know yet.

Comment: @elb98rm I see a User class consuming a Postcode class inside a method. it's a case of hidden dependency. I know what you are trying to do, but doing it outside in a seperate method (for example `$postcode = Postcode::findByPCD($value);`) would make more sense and make it more testable without the need to mock eloquent methods. Move the lookup to its own unit testing for Postcode class.

Comment: Sure. Can you tell me how to test the static call `Postcode::findByPCD($value)`? 
Moving it elsewhere is nice, and I agree with a refactor, but it doesn't answer the question which I need the answer to first.

Comment: @elb98rm well you can still create the static method `findByPCD()` and use **it** inside the `setPostcodeAttribute()` which will make it mockable easily. If you are still asking about how to mock the Whole eloquent Builder class the "right way".... it's not gonna be a fun ride, it's a pretty complex structure. If you want just so you can get by, try mocking the method `first()` present in the trait `Illuminate\Database\Concerns\BuildsQueries`

Comment: My approach already tries to mock `->first();` ... that's where I'd got to.

The point is that this is an example, there are/will be other similar examples. 
If you want 100% code coverage (which we will), this is going to have to be done.

Comment: I would not create a class with _static_ functions, if you want to test this, I would create a normal class, make it a facade, and then you can fake and test that, it is going to be way easier than mocking a static class